# What is the easiest way to use Python in Hive UDF other than using Jython?

Tags: python, hive

Worst case I guess I could implement a UDF that spawns a process etc. but wanted to know if somebody has already done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transform in hiveql which is effectively a way to do hadoop streaming.

In hive cli type

```
FILE ${env:HOME}/myscript.py; //you do not need this if your script is guaranteed to be installed on a cluster, this just adds script to cache.

SELECT TRANSFORM(someColumn) USING 'myscript.py' AS convert FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I should use Hive's streaming functionality instead ([link](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-transform.html)). This allows use of arbitrary scripts.